# Optimise comparing data in two big MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

How could I optimise query, which will find all records, which:

- have activation_request.date_confirmed not null

and

- do not have related string value in another table: activation_request.email =
  user.username shouldn't return any record

I tried:

```
SELECT  email 
FROM activation_request l 
    LEFT JOIN user r ON r.username = l.email 
WHERE l.date_confirmed is not null 
AND r.username IS NULL
```

and

```
SELECT email 
FROM  activation_request 
WHERE  date_confirmed is not null 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM user  
                WHERE  user.username = activation_request.email
                )
```

but both tables have xxx.xxx.xxx records hence after all night running those queries unfortunatelly  I haven't got any results.

Create statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `activation_request` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_confirmed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  (...)
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `emailIdx` (`email`),
  KEY `reminderSentIdx` (`date_reminder_sent`),
  KEY `idx_resent_needed` (`date_reminder_sent`,`date_confirmed`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=103011867 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  (...)
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Q52plW9W7TJWZcLj00K3FmuhwMSw4F7vmxJGyjxz5iiINVR9fXyacEoq4rHppb` (`username`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=431400048 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Explain for LEFT JOIN:

> [[id:1, select_type:SIMPLE, table:l, type:ALL, possible_keys:null,
>   key:null, key_len:null, ref:null, rows:49148965, Extra:Using where],
>   [id:1, select_type:SIMPLE, table:r, type:index, possible_keys:null,
>   key:Q52plW9W7TJWZcLj00K3FmuhwMSw4F7vmxJGyjxz5iiINVR9fXyacEoq4rHppb,
>   key_len:257, ref:null, rows:266045508, Extra:Using where; Not exists;
>   Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)]] [[id:1,
>   select_type:SIMPLE, table:l, type:ALL, possible_keys:null, key:null,
>   key_len:null, ref:null, rows:49148965, Extra:Using where], [id:1,
>   select_type:SIMPLE, table:r, type:index, possible_keys:null,
>   key:Q52plW9W7TJWZcLj00K3FmuhwMSw4F7vmxJGyjxz5iiINVR9fXyacEoq4rHppb,
>   key_len:257, ref:null, rows:266045508, Extra:Using where; Not exists;
>   Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)]]

After adding indexes on staging db (with slightly less data, but the same structure) query is now running ~24h and still no results):

```
$ show processlist;

| Id | User    | Host                                            | db       | Command | Time   | State        | Info 
| 64 | root    | localhost                                       | staging_db   | Query   | 110072 | Sending data | SELECT ar.email FROM  activation_request ar WHERE ar.date_confirmed is not null AND NOT EXISTS (SELE |
```

Mysql version:

```
$ select version();
5.6.16-1~exp1
```

All other commands on the list are `Sleep` so there is no other query running and possibly disturbing/locking rows.

Comment: Both methods should get the job done efficiently. Do you have any indexes on the tables? Please show the create table statements for both tables.

Comment: ...as well as the EXPLAIN

Comment: Try an index on `activation_request (date_confirmed, email)` or `activation_request (email, date_confirmed)`.

Comment: I have done it. Query is running approx. 24h now and no result.

Comment: Do you have an estimate of what percentage of rows in `activation_request` have `date_confirmed is not null` ?  How much RAM do you have?  Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for those two tables.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT ar.email 
FROM  activation_request ar
WHERE ar.date_confirmed is not null AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM user u
                  WHERE u.username = ar.email
                 )
```

I would recommend indexes on `activation_request(date_confirmed, email)` and `user(username)`.

Unless you have a really humongous amount of data, though, your problem may be that tables are locked.

Comment: I have created a staging db with full dump, added those indexes and as for now, the query is running for 13 hours...