# Monitor the output file while running the long MySQL query into that output file

Tags: mysql, monitoring, query-performance

So I have very long running MySQL query: [Optimise comparing data in two big MySQL tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669491/optimise-comparing-data-in-two-big-mysql-tables)

Apparently there are results: after interrupting the query I have found that the output file was indeed modified and has several thousands of records. However **the results were flushed into the file in the moment when I interrupted the long running query**.

I have used command:

`mysql> SELECT ar.email FROM  activation_request ar WHERE ar.date_confirmed is not null AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user u WHERE u.username = ar.email) INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/results_after_adding_indexes.csv';`

How can I monitor/tee it meanwhile? The file was created in the filesystem but it's empty (until the end or interruption of the query; whatever comes first).

Answer (score 0):

Since `INTO OUTFILE` has no supporting [options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) for paging the output, I believe you'll need to write your own export script.

(Note, you can see also `LOAD DATA` [options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) for completeness, as instructed by the `INTO OUTFILE` documentation, but the only hopeful is a `LINES` option, which is for custom line delimeters.)

Assuming you don't need DB engine options on record lines, the script is a simple:

1. A "gimme all" version of your report/export query -- unless your dataset is too big for that, in which case, include a paging loop;
2. looping on the results to do a simple transform;
3. store your outgoing lines in an array on its way to the file;
4. write that queue to the file every *n* lines;
5. And make sure not to drop the final bits of the record set just because they don't contain *n* lines in the final block.

Comment: I don't want "gimme all" query. I do want to monitor appearing results one by one and than store them somewhere (file is just fine)

Comment: Sure. I edited to be clearer and more specific to your question. Bottom line is (I believe) you will be writing a script, even if it's just to add a paging loop to the existing `SELECT` component of your export query.

Comment: what do you mean by "own export script"? how does it apply to the presented query? have you got any (similar) example?

Comment: "Own export script" means you're going to have to write a script in a scripting language like node or php (or a proper programming language, if you prefer). It pertains to the presented query because, when you need more features than the database engine presents, you need to provide those features yourself via a script or program that connects to the database like a client. I'm afraid the outline above is going to have to suffice for an example. Apologies if you were looking for a complete solution. If you were, I strongly recommend you post your schemas and generally expand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some queries run linearly.  That is, they produce another row at a regular pace.

Some queries do 99% of the work before emitting even the 'first' row.  This is easily seen if the query has an `ORDER BY`.

Some *connections* compute the *entire* result before sending *anything* back to the client.  Some connections chunk the output.

The connection problem may be solvable.  But it is simply not practical to "monitor" a query with something like a sort.

Comment: Sure, but it's not the case this time, right? I'm not using ordering, sorting or I have not to compute entire dataset before receiving proper results (cause in case of interruption I wouldn't get any result). Unfortunately your answer seems out of topic.

Comment: However, there could be a long run of `NOT EXIST` returning false, thereby leading to a 'long' time between rows being generated.

Comment: So `SELECT  email FROM activation_request l LEFT JOIN user r ON r.username = l.email WHERE l.date_confirmed is not null AND r.username IS NULL` in your opinion should be faster?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc - Hard to say.  Try both.

Comment: I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669491/optimise-comparing-data-in-two-big-mysql-tables both need ages to finish and I can not monitor results.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query, correct?  And the PK is `id`, correct?

```
SELECT  l.email 
    FROM activation_request l 
    LEFT JOIN user r ON r.username = l.email 
    WHERE l.date_confirmed is not null 
      AND r.username IS NULL
```

Using some application code, create a loop on `id`, perhaps 10,000 at a time:

```
SELECT  l.email 
    FROM activation_request l 
    LEFT JOIN user r ON r.username = l.email 
    WHERE l.date_confirmed is not null 
      AND r.username IS NULL
      AND l.id BETWEEN 1 AND 10000;   -- added
```

Time that; then change the last line to

```
      AND l.id BETWEEN 10001 AND 20000;
```

Etc.

This will:

- Provide the desired list of rows with missing users, albeit piecemeal.
- After the first chunk, you can extrapolate to deduce the anticipated total time.
- After several chunks, you might get a feel for whether it is varying in speed.
- You could put the data together to give a progress bar.

The above assumes that the `ids` are 'dense'; that is no ids deleted.  If there are deleted ids, then the chunks will not be a consistent 10000 rows (but, rather, fewer rows).  That can be resolved by using `SELECT id FROM .. WHERE id > $leftoff ORDER BY id .. LIMIT 10000,1` to find out the next end-point.

More on Chunking:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks  (Caution: that talks about deleting.)

If you do a few chunks by the `NOT EXISTS` method, you can get a feel for which is faster.  Caution:  run twice to avoid caching messing up the timings.